# Skip devise authentication and authorization for a particular action in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have been working on a system in which the user needs to verify the account using email but when the user click on the link to verify to activate his account the system show the login page. How the user can login if his account is not active yet . I just need to skip the authentication, authorization for that particular action in which the "account active" functionality is written.

I have used

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => :active_account
```

but it is not working.Kindly help me.

Thanks

The logs are

```
Started GET "/admins/active_account/6beoG6zUYLdY9uiohITPFw" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-10-19 14:46:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at /vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4)
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <class:AdminsController> at /vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:4)
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <class:AdminsController> at /vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:11)
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <class:AdminsController> at /vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:14)
Processing by AdminsController#active_account as HTML
  Parameters: {"token"=>"6beoG6zUYLdY9uiohITPFw"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-10-19 14:46:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/admin
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/admin (2.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 362ms (Views: 331.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
```

Comment: How is it not working? Whats the response code? What queries do you see in your server logs? Where is the code stopping? `:active_account` is your action name?

Comment: active_account is my action name. When I click on the link that is route to the action "active_account" then the login page appears

Comment: Show us the relevant code and server logs when this happens.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:active_account]`

Comment: @Cyzanfar not working bro.

Comment: hmmm.. Could you post your server log. That would help

Comment: @Cyzanfar are you talking about the logs inside development.log file?

Comment: Yup, logs that relate to when you are accessing that specific route `active_account`

Comment: @Cyzanfar edited the question please check it.

Comment: @Leito kindly check the edited question

Comment: Is this an  active admin route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157071/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-john).

Comment: How is called your user model? Is really User? 'Cause if its not, you gotta change to skip authenticate_your_model_name

Comment: Also, where did you placed that piece of code? Is it on the controller who contains that active_account action?

Comment: @RonanLopes I am using devise and I have put a "admin" field in the database to differ the normal user and the admin.The code is in controller named "admins" and the action name is "active_account". I am using devise not active_admin gem.